# python multiprocessing process.join() waits forever

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to Python multiprocessing and for the life of me I cant figure this one out. Basically I have a task that takes quite some time that I need to repeatedly do 100s of times. Each time I modify a common resource to the processes.
So I want to launch 4 processes in batches wait for them to be done and then launch the next 4.
Here is my main function

```
lock = Lock() #global defined at the start of my file
myObj = MyObj()
processes = []
for num in range(1,100):
    if len(processes) < 5:
        p = Process(target=myObj.longFunc, args =())
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    else:
        for proc in processes:
            proc.join()
        processes = []
```

Here is the MyObj.longFunc fonction:

```
def longFunc:
    lock.acquire()
    #Do stuff on common resourse which is a multiprocessing.Queue object
    lock.release()
    #Do more stuff
    print 'process should return'
    return 0
```

I get the following ouput:

```
process should return
process should return
process should return
process should return
process should return
```

And then the program just waits there 'forever'.
Doesnt the output mean the processes are done running and the next batch of processes should be created? What am I missing.
Thanks in advance! and sorry if its a stupid questions Im a newbie :)

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a self contained example that exhibits the behavior you are experiencing. What you have here cannot possibly be the code you are running.

Comment: Why are you iterating 100 times if you only need 5?

Comment: you should also terminate your processes with `proc.terminate()`

Comment: Thx for your reply! yes serdalis I think you are right although my main function is exactly as written above. Should I just dump my code in the question? its about 120lines

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code example which attempts to mimic your question I get a successful execution and return of the program (Python 2.7.7):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

lock = Lock()

class MyObj():
    def longFunc(self):
        lock.acquire()
        #Do stuff on common resourse which is a multiprocessing.Queue object
        lock.release()
        print "process should return"
        return 0

myObj = MyObj()
processes = []
x = 0

for num in range(1,100):
    if len(processes) < 5:
        p = Process(target=myObj.longFunc, args =())
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    else:
        for proc in processes:
            proc.join()
            x += 1
            print x, " joined"
        processes = []
```

This indicates that the problem does not lay with the way you are starting and joining threads, but with some other part of your program.

As a note, I notice this program only gets to `80 joined` because your loop is taking up some cycles joining the threads instead of starting them, this may or may not be intended behavior.